# PRelue is not supperted with mmdnn?

Tags: caffe, pytorch, pycaffe

I converted my caffe model to IR successfully, error happened when I tried convert IR to pytorch:

```
Pytorch Emitter has not supported operator [PRelu]
```

How should I deal with that please?

Comment: This is known issue with MMdnn they are working on fix. https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/issues/450

Comment: https://github.com/marvis/pytorch-caffe This doesn't support `PReLu` but you can try implementing it.

Comment: @papabiceps Does mmdnn support LeakyRelu for converting from pytorch to caffe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes MMdnn support supports `LeakyRelu`. Check the link below for `pytorch_emitter.py` implementation from MMdnn.

> [pytorch_emitter.py](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/blob/master/mmdnn/conversion/pytorch/pytorch_emitter.py#L805)

If you check the implementation you will find all the supported operations and it doesn't include `PRelu`.